# java.lang.VerifyError during ejb method call

Tags: java, ejb

When I try to call a method from a local ejb I have this error :

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/pwc/lu/ejb/hcfollowup/staff/HCFStaffManagerLocal.getPersonById(Ljava/lang/Integer;)Lcom/pwc/lu/mapping/hcfollowup/hibernate/global/Person;
```

HCFStaffManagerLocal is my local interface and getPersonById an ejb method. Person, the result type.

I can get my ejb but error occurs when trying to call getPersonById method.

I don't understand why it get an exception for Person class...

Any ideas ?

Comment: could be a bug in JDK 1.5 - which version you using?

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror) on VerifyError has a lot of good answers - hope one leads to a solution!

There's a chance that the compiled Person class is corrupt and it's worth a try to recompile it with a different java SDK.

Comment: Do you think that ejb interface method getPersonById(Integer personId) and ejb method call : getPersonbyId(int) can be an issue ?

Comment: No. The Error indicates that the (binary) Person class is corrupt and can't be loaded into the virtual machine. The problem is outside the Java code.

Comment: Ok I will try to rebuild the entire project

Comment: I have news : 

My application works with IceFaces jsf framework. To use it I have to inverse the classloader of the web module. When I don't do it, there is no problem with my ejb call. 
Problems only occurs when the classloader is inversed...

I don't understand