# Android :- Second activity not getting started?

Tags: android

My second activity is not starting.
Below is the code :-

First Activity :-

```
package infy.route;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class main extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Context mCtx;
    final static int START =0;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.welcomescreen);

      mCtx = this;
      Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            try {
               int waited = 0;
               while (waited < 2500) {
                  sleep(100);
                  waited += 100;
               }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               // do nothing
            } finally {
               finish();
               Intent i = new Intent(mCtx,InfyRoutePlanner.class);
               mCtx.startActivity(i);
               ((Activity)mCtx).startActivityForResult(i, 2);
            }
         }
      };
      splashThread.start();
   }
   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == START)
        {

            Toast.makeText(mCtx, Integer.toString(resultCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        finish();
    }

}
```

Second Activity :-

```
package infy.route;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class InfyRoutePlanner extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Context mCtx;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mCtx = this;

        // Setting the buttons with their xml
        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        // Button for Prepare Route By Address  ( Line 30 is this one)
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

//          @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // This will start the From Address Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, FromAddress.class);

            /*Start Activity*/
            mCtx.startActivity(intent);

            /*Start ActivityForResult*/
            ((Activity)mCtx).startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
        }
        });


        // Action On Clicking Button 2
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        //  @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // This will start the activity RoutePlanning using Lat and Long Values
            Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, RoutePlanning.class);

            /*Start Activity*/
            mCtx.startActivity(intent);

            /*Start ActivityForResult*/
            ((Activity)mCtx).startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
        }
    });
}


}
```

Here is the stack tracer :-

```
02-18 20:10:02.253: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(299): Shutting down VM
02-18 20:10:02.263: WARN/dalvikvm(299): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
02-18 20:10:02.263: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299): java.lang.VerifyError: infy.route.InfyRoutePlanner$1
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at infy.route.InfyRoutePlanner.onCreate(InfyRoutePlanner.java:30)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
02-18 20:10:02.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is related to your problem, but you are starting the activity twice in your `activity main`

```
mCtx.startActivity(i);
((Activity)mCtx).startActivityForResult(i, 2);
```

The first time without expecting a result, the second one expecting it. Normally, you would start an activity only once. And the same 'issue' you have it twice in your `activity InfyRoutePlanner`
Now, for your problem, have you checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)?
I hope that helps

Comment: what to do if i want a splash screen which starts second page and in second page i am having two buttons which start different activities

Comment: you should only need to start it without expecting a result, unless you need the second activity to let know the first activity about specific scenarios. For a better explanation, see the StartingActivities and Getting Results section in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 2):

Are you including any 3rd party jars? A VeryifyError is thrown when the virtual machine notices that an attempt is made to load a class which does not pass the class verification phase.

Also you have 2 calls to startActivity in each OnClickListener.

Comment: I am not including any other jar, the code is working fine if i an making the second activity the main activity. I want to add a splash screen to my project thats why added the splash screen. please help.

Comment: @James - Have you added the second activity to your manifest?

Comment: @Blundell second activity is present in manifest. but still not working

Comment: what to do if i want a splash screen which starts second page and in second page i am having two buttons which start different activities

Comment: i have made the splash screen my main activity , is it ok