# problem trying to use java mail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to use the java Mail API in my program, i have the library added to my package folder but when i go to run the program it says that it cant find class `javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress` but when i open the library i can see the class file there...so what gives?

```
04-21 10:30:25.202: ERROR/dalvikvm(3065): Could not find class 'javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress', referenced from method com.app.notifyme.GmailReciever.createNotification
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065): java.lang.VerifyError: com.app.notifyme.GmailReciever
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1885)
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:989)
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3839)
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-21 10:30:30.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3065):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You might take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror  It talks about verify errors.  My guess is that you have differences between your compile and runtime classpaths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're missing the Activation API (usually called `activation.jar`), which is a dependency of JavaMail. If you don't have it, you'll get confusing classloading exceptions like this one.

`activation.jar` is usually found alongside `mail.jar`.

P.S. Fir future reference, if you want to ask about an exception on Stackoverflow, then *show us* the exception.

Comment: there is no activation.jar so where do i get it then?

Comment: @tyczj: Try http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/javax/xml/bind/activation/1.0.2/activation-1.0.2.jar

Comment: added the file, i no longer get the cannot find class error but i still get everything else

Answer (score 0):

A nifty site is [jarFinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php). When I put your above class in it, jarFinder lists 14 versions in 110 different jar packages.

The big question is whether you have any of those jars in your classpath. I'm thinking you will need to add it with a set classpath command.