# Getting RunTimeError while writing Junit with EasyMock?

Tags: java, junit

i am writing the junit using easy mock for my program. Below is the test method

```
public static void doBeforeEachTestCase() {

private static FibanocciProg mock;

mock = EasyMock.createMock(FibanocciProg.class);

     FibanocciProg testObject= new FibanocciProg();

    EasyMock.expect(mock.recursionFib1(6)).andReturn(50);
    EasyMock.replay(mock);
    int actual = testObject.recursionFib1(6);

 }
```

I am getting below error in eclipse while EasyMock.createMock. The libs i have downloaded for easy mock are:- easymock-3.0,cglib-2.2.2,asm-4.0_RC2

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.<init>(AbstractClassGenerator.java:38)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.<init>(KeyFactory.java:127)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:112)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createEnhancer(ClassProxyFactory.java:259)
at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory.createProxy(ClassProxyFactory.java:174)
at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:60)
at org.easymock.EasyMock.createMock(EasyMock.java:104)
at TestMock.doBeforeEachTestCase(TestMock.java:19)
at TestMock.main(TestMock.java:13)
```

**Any Pointers?**

Comment: Is your `recursionFib1` `final`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong version of the dependencies for Easymock. Looking at the [maven pom for EasyMock 3.0](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/easymock/easymock/3.0/easymock-3.0.pom), the dependencies are:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
    <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

or the [EasyMock documentation](http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html):

> Requirements
>
> - EasyMock only works with Java 1.5.0 and above.
> - cglib (2.2) and Objenesis (1.2) must be in the classpath to perform
>     class mocking

So you're using version 2.2.2 rather than 2.2. java.lang.VerifyError generally happens when you've compiled against one library but then are executing against another version of the library.

See the answers to [Reasons of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror) and the javadoc for [java.lang.VerifyError](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html)

Note: to find the above dependency details, you simply need to search on [Maven Search](http://search.maven.org).

Comment: Thanks Mathew. It worked. One more question where we can figure out this kind of jar version dependency? i mean where  did you get code snippet above stating dependency details?

Comment: added how to find dependencies