# Error while using java agent

Tags: java, profiler, javaagents

I tried to build a profiler using http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jip/

One of my java applications when executed in command prompt

```
java -jar abc.jar
```

gives required output, but when using a javaagent to profile the same application gives error

```
java -javaagent:profiler.jar -jar abc.jar
```

gives the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at
branch target 20 in method 
()V at offset 12
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

But there are also some swing applications which is running fine with the above javaagent method.

Comment: What JDK version are you using to build your profiler and application?

Comment: Please check this post and see if anything applies to your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you are running your target JVM on JDK6? JDK 7 tightened up the checks performed on stack map frames and this can lead to such VerifyError exceptions when the bytecode has been modified by tools unaware of these changes.

Double check the target JVM and if you find you are using JDK 7 you can either switch to JDK 6 or use "-XX:-UseSplitVerifier" switch to change the verifier back to JDK 6 version.

Comment: how to use  "-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"