# VerifyError in web-service operation using SOAP only in Android 4.2?

Tags: android, web-services, soap, verifyerror

I am getting  **java.lang.VerifyError** in call Webservice communicator class.

This Error is seen **only in Android 4.2 O.S devices.** And its working well on all other devices of OS and Tabs too.

below are my logs:

```
01-09 06:15:10.263: E/AndroidRuntime(785): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-78
01-09 06:15:10.263: E/AndroidRuntime(785): java.lang.VerifyError: org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope
01-09 06:15:10.263: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.weg.ecatalogue.servercommunication.WebServiceCommunicator$2.run(WebServiceCommunicator.java:78)
01-09 06:15:10.263: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Please suggest me, about this 4.2 OS dependent issue.

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: I have gone through this post earlier also and applied few changes but it didn't worked yet...

Answer (score 7):

Use this jar file for call soap webservices

```
ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies .jar
```

And replace `AndroidHttpTransport` class to `HttpTransportSE`

Comment: Thanks a-lot @hharry...Till now I ws running this application on plateforms below 4.2. You solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on ksoap2-android-2.5.2.jar file. Earlier we pasted that file on lib folder,right click and selected set as a library from the menu. That worked fine with an emulator but crashed when using real devices. Then we deleted the jar file from the lib folder and added these to Gradle.

Solution : 
add this snippet into buildTypes

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
```

add this snippet into dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1'
```

and also remove jar file from libs