# Where to find Ksoap2 2.6 with timeout

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I've used "ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.2-jar-with-dependencies_timeout1.jar"

when I'm trying to lunch it on android 4.4 (KitKat)

I've got an error

```
Could not find class 'org.kxml2.kdom.Node', referenced from method org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parseBody

Could not find class 'org.kxml2.kdom.Node', referenced from method org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parseHeader

Could not find class 'org.kxml2.kdom.Node', referenced from method org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.writeBody

java.lang.VerifyError: org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope
```

I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229448/verifyerror-in-web-service-operation-using-soap-only-in-android-4-2)

so where to find Ksoap2 2.6.2 with timeout ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make modification in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229448/verifyerror-in-web-service-operation-using-soap-only-in-android-4-2)

and use the latest version of Ksoap2 [here](http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/3.3.0/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar)

Comment: Glad because you found useful answer