# Should I upgrade to CGLIB 3.0?

Tags: java, cglib

I would like to know if/why I should upgrade CGLib 2.2.2 to Version 3.0. I am using CGLib with the latest versions of Hibernate/Spring/Mockito and Java 7.

I can not find release notes or upgrade directions for this version anywhere on the web.

Comment: Which versions? It's not helpful unless you tell us all the versions you are using.

Comment: Hibernate 4.1.4.Final, Spring 3.1.3.RELEASE, Mockito 1.9.0, Java 1.7.0_09

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you should migrate to CGLib 3.1 because it can correctly generate stack map frame and deal with Java 7 bytecode.

### Update

The following issues were all addressed by CGLib 3.1

<del>We're using EasyMock and switched to a custom version of CGLIB 3. We switched because code coverage with EclEmma/JaCoCo/Sonar would no longer work. It was more or less a drop in replacement (apart from updating POMs). Unfortunately</del>

- <del>CGLIB 3 is not (yet) in Maven Central</del>
- <del>CGLIB 3 has a blocker bug https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3601081&group_id=56933&atid=482368 so we had to build a custom version and deployed it to our in-house Nexus</del>

<del>So if you don't currently have any issues like code coverage no longer working I would not switch.</del>

Comment: cglib3 is now in maven central. The bug mentioned above however is still open for the time being

Comment: Amazing, unfortunately it says it's fixed in 1.0. I don't know if that means 3.1.