# java.lang.VerifyError on ajmrtd project

Tags: android, nfc

I downloaded the ajmrtd android application from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ajmrtd/?source=directory and  I was trying to read android.nfc.tech.IsoDep using it but when I was debugging the program I faced the following error , How can I solve that ?

```
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799): java.lang.VerifyError: de/maxmg/mrtd/readerapp/service/MRTDConnection
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at de.maxmg.mrtd.readerapp.ReadAct.handleIsoDepFound(ReadAct.java:197)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at de.maxmg.mrtd.readerapp.ReadAct.resolveIntent(ReadAct.java:133)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at de.maxmg.mrtd.readerapp.ReadAct.onCreate(ReadAct.java:103)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5191)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
02-08 20:36:17.344: E/AndroidRuntime(21799):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.VerifyError can be the result when you have compiled against a different library than you are using at runtime or there had been changes to the classes and methods, so that the method signatures found at runtime did not match what was there at compile-time.

I would suggest making sure you do a full clean of the project and also checking the build path contains all the right libraries and configurations.