# Connecting to a java DB with java program

Tags: java, netbeans

I am implementing a simple tutorial that

connects a java program to a java DB
using the NetBeans 7 IDE
.
Here is the link to the tutorials.

```
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/connect_to_a_database_using_java_code.html
```

But when I run the project, NetBeans gives me the following error:

```
run:
java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return in method   database_console.DBConnect.<init>()V at offset 0
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:492)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:484)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
```

Below is the code for the project

```
    package database_console;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

  public static void main(String[] args) {           
            try {
          String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
          String uName="faisal";
          String uPass="password";
          Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);        
            }
           catch ( SQLException err ) {
    System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
    }
        }
    }
```

any available suggestion to solve this problem

Comment: Is that your real code (no more, no less)?

Comment: Please post your whole code (yes, don't mind if it's a code wall).

Comment: yes that is the whole code@Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the class definition? Otherwise your code would have never compiled to begin with (and no way to run it).

Comment: @faisalabdulai, then you don't have class declaration

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, my first answer was correct. But you downvoted, I tried removing class. I am getting same error OP is getting

Comment: @PradeepSimha ok, undelete it and I will upvote it (since you were the first one to find the problem).

Comment: If you have an IDE how did it even allow you to run that program ?

Comment: I dont think the issue is with the class missing - he would have forgot to paste it here - See the discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not follow the [tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/connect_to_a_database_using_java_code.html) you linked correctly.

Your code should look like this:

```
package database_console;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnect {  // <--- This is missing from your code

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
            String uName = "faisal";
            String uPass = "password";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        } catch (SQLException err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }  // <--- This is also missing from your code
}
```

And it should be in a file named `DBConnect.java` in a package called `database_console`

Comment: You should point that the code comes from the [tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/connect_to_a_database_using_java_code.html) not from the top of your head.

Comment: Yes exactly. OP sais it in the question

Comment: after trying your suggstion , now the NetBeans IDE underlines he class declaration with the following message duplicate class database_console.DBConnect

Comment: @faisalabdulai Delete the entire contents of the file `DBConnect.java` and paste the above code. It should give no compiler errors. You have something else in there that is not showing.

Comment: @faisalabdulai Also clean the project and build again

Answer (score 2):

If your above code is what you are using, then you need to put your entire code in class.

```
//Package declarations (if any)
//Import packages
public class className {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Other code
    }
}
```

Comment: but thought the public clas className in the above code is the class declaration

Comment: @faisalabdulai, in your code don't have either public or non-public class.

Answer (score 1):

Please add class to your main(). Like following

```
package database_console;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnect 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
            String uName = "faisal";
            String uPass = "password";
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        } 
        catch (SQLException err) 
        {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this class is used to create DB connection

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.*;

public class GetDBConnection 
{
    public static Connection getConnection(String[] args) 
    {
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
        String uName="faisal";
        String uPass="password";
        Connection con=null;
        try 
        {
              con=DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);        
        }
        catch ( SQLException err ) 
        {
        System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
        }
        return con;
    }

}
```

this class is used to get coonection and use it

```
public class UseDBConnection 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        GetDBConnection object = new GetDBConnection();
        System.out.println("now you can use this DB like you want it and can create as many connection as you want");
    }
}
```