# OAuth+GetGlue = getQueryParameter returns null

Tags: android, oauth, callback

I'm trying to do check'ins to GetGlue using [GetGlue API](http://getglue.com/api). I have this [code](http://pastebin.com/ezvSHJNb) from [SeriesGuide GitHub](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/SeriesGuide/blob/master/SeriesGuide/src/com/battlelancer/seriesguide/getglueapi).

I'm new with Oauth and I don't know why it doesn't work because

```
 uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
```

returns always null and

```
mProvider.retrieveAccessToken(mConsumer, oauth_verifier);
```

gives and exception.

This is the console log:

```
05-01 17:51:58.098: E/PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4790): OAuth - Access Token Retrieval Error
05-01 17:51:58.098: E/PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4790): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException: Request token or token secret not set in server reply. The service provider you use is probably buggy.
05-01 17:51:58.098: E/PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4790):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:206)
05-01 17:51:58.098: E/PrepareRequestTokenActivity(4790):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveAccessToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:108)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the new [getglue-java library](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/getglue-java) which will replace the code you are currently using in SeriesGuide. It uses the new v3 API end points and easier to handle OAuth 2.0 for authentication.

Check out the [README](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/getglue-java/blob/master/README.md) for up-to date instructions.

Comment: I can't use your library. I get java.lang.VerifyError: 

org/apache/oltu/oauth2/client/response/OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse

and I am using this jars: YoutubeAndroidPlayerApi, universal-image-loader, gson2.2.4, okhttp1.2.1, apache.oauth2.client0.31, apache.oauth2.common0.31, retrofit1.2.2, libgoogleanalyticsv2 and android-suport-v7.   Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to use the new Apache Oltu OAuth library! E.g. org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client v0.31. See http://oltu.apache.org/download.html.

Comment: Yes, those are what I am using but maybe there is a conflict with another library :(

Comment: You might want to look at [this comment on VerifyError](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2518002/1000543). It sounds silly, but make sure that you actually export the Oltu OAuth library jars.

Comment: I was searching in the maven repository, and I found the problem. This library is also needed: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jettison/jettison/1.3.4