# Unfortunately app has stopped working when i add number of records to save

Tags: android

I am working on an app which saves up to 30 records at once,when I cut down to 10 records I can access the activity and save the records but if I add the code to save more records the app crashes.

Below is my code

```
        case R.id.BSaveAll:
        boolean diditworkAll = true;

        try {
            String observe1 = Observation1.getText().toString();
            String observe2 = Observation2.getText().toString();
            String observe3 = Observation3.getText().toString();
            String observe4 = Observation4.getText().toString();
            String observe5 = Observation5.getText().toString();
            String observe6 = Observation6.getText().toString();
            String observe7 = Observation7.getText().toString();
            String observe8 = Observation8.getText().toString();
            String observe9 = Observation9.getText().toString();
            String observe10 = Observation10.getText().toString();
            String observe11 = Observation11.getText().toString();
            String observe12 = Observation12.getText().toString();
            String observe13 = Observation13.getText().toString();
            String observe14 = Observation14.getText().toString();
            String observe15 = Observation15.getText().toString();

            DBContractor con1 = new DBContractor(this);
            con1.open();
            String lastid1 = con1.getConstructorId();
            con1.close();
            String construct1 = lastid1;

            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable11 = (BitmapDrawable) view1_1
                    .getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap11 = bitmapDrawable11.getBitmap();
            byte[] image1_1 = DBManagement.getBytes(bitmap11);

            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable12 = (BitmapDrawable) view1_2
                    .getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap12 = bitmapDrawable12.getBitmap();
            byte[] image1_2 = DBManagement.getBytes(bitmap12);

            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable13 = (BitmapDrawable) view1_3
                    .getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap13 = bitmapDrawable13.getBitmap();
            byte[] image1_3 = DBManagement.getBytes(bitmap13);

            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable14 = (BitmapDrawable) view1_4
                    .getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap14 = bitmapDrawable14.getBitmap();
            byte[] image1_4 = DBManagement.getBytes(bitmap14);

            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable15 = (BitmapDrawable) view1_5
                    .getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap15 = bitmapDrawable15.getBitmap();
            byte[] image1_5 = DBManagement.getBytes(bitmap15);

            DBManagement entry1 = new DBManagement(this);

            entry1.open();
            entry1.createEntry1(title1, Possible1, Achieved1, observe1,
                    image1_1, image1_2, image1_3, image1_4, image1_5,
                    construct1);

            entry1.close();

            DBContractor con2 = new DBContractor(this);
            con2.open();
            String lastid2 = con2.getConstructorId();
            con2.close();
            String construct2 = lastid2;

            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable21 = (BitmapDrawable) view2_1
                    .getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap21 = bitmapDrawable21.getBitmap();
            byte[] image2_1 = DBManagement.getBytes(bitmap21);

            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable22 = (BitmapDrawable) view2_2
                    .getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap22 = bitmapDrawable22.getBitmap();
            byte[] image2_2 = DBManagement.getBytes(bitmap22);

            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable23 = (BitmapDrawable) view2_3
                    .getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap23 = bitmapDrawable23.getBitmap();
            byte[] image2_3 = DBManagement.getBytes(bitmap23);

            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable24 = (BitmapDrawable) view2_4
                    .getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap24 = bitmapDrawable24.getBitmap();
            byte[] image2_4 = DBManagement.getBytes(bitmap24);

            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable25 = (BitmapDrawable) view2_5
                    .getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap25 = bitmapDrawable25.getBitmap();
            byte[] image2_5 = DBManagement.getBytes(bitmap25);

            DBManagement entry2 = new DBManagement(this);

            entry2.open();
            entry2.createEntry2(title2, Possible2, Achieved2, observe2,
                    image2_1, image2_2, image2_3, image2_4, image2_5,
                    construct2);

            entry2.close();
                             } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

            diditworkAll = false;

            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed,please try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } finally {

            if (diditworkAll) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfull,proceed to Appointment",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        break;`


05-13 18:44:40.536: W/dalvikvm(431): VFY: arbitrarily rejecting large method (regs=365 count=8384)
05-13 18:44:40.536: W/dalvikvm(431): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/mba_north/Management;.onClick (Landroid/view/View;)V
05-13 18:44:40.546: W/dalvikvm(431): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/mba_north/Management;
05-13 18:44:40.556: W/dalvikvm(431): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/mba_north/Management;)
05-13 18:44:40.556: D/AndroidRuntime(431): Shutting down VM
05-13 18:44:40.556: W/dalvikvm(431): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431): java.lang.VerifyError: com.example.mba_north.Management
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-13 18:44:40.586: E/AndroidRuntime(431):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check [out this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2518002/2345913)

Comment: Please post your logcat of the error you're getting

Comment: The logcat is below the code.