# Handling java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, lucene

I have written a Java Program using Lucene in Eclipse Juno. Whenever I try to run it, it is giving the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at parser.BuildMainIndex.setUp(BuildMainIndex.java:339)
at parser.luceneDemo.main(luceneDemo.java:10)
```

and source of the error i.e. the line in BuildManinIndex.java is:

```
        doc.add(new IntField("startTime1",startTime1,Field.Store.YES));
```

Here startTime1 is a field in document to be indexed. I was earlier using Lucene 3.6.0 and now I am using Lucene 4.3.0. I have not imported any thing from java.net.URL. I have no clue of the possible cause of this error. Please help.

**EDIT:** This following short program I have written.

```
writer=new IndexWriter(directory,new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT),IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

Document doc=new Document();
doc.add(new Field("title","XYZ",Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("address","ABC Road",Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.add(new Field("city","Mumbai",Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.add(new IntField("startTime1",900,Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new IntField("finishTime1",1000,Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new IntField("startTime2",9999,Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new IntField("finishTime2",9999,Field.Store.YES));

writer.addDocument(doc);
writer.close();
```

Comment: That doesn't look like it would cause that problem. Can you reproduce this with a short but *complete* program? Have you rebuilt everything from scratch against Lucence 4.3.0?

Comment: Okay Sir I am trying it.

Comment: Yes Sir. Error is still coming. Now i Have written a short program for just adding one document in the index. Whenever I comment this line error disappears.

Comment: Please post that short but complete program, so that we can reproduce it for ourselves.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sir, have you got any clue to solve the problem?

Comment: No, please post a short but *complete* program. One that anyone can copy, paste into a new file, compile against Lucene 4.3.0, and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a bit confusing because you are not inheriting the `IntField` class, you are creating an instance of it, right?

```
doc.add(new IntField("startTime1", startTime1, Field.Store.YES));
```

The problem is in the first part of that statement `doc.add(..)`.
There was a change to the `Document` class between Lucene versions 3.6.0 and 4.x - `add(..)` in 3.6 is accepting `Fieldable` ([class API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#add%28org.apache.lucene.document.Fieldable%29)), and in 4.1.0 is accepting `IndexableField` ([class API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#add%28org.apache.lucene.index.IndexableField%29)).

Useful [article](http://craftingjava.blogspot.com/2012/08/3-reasons-for-javalangverfiyerror.html) on the `VerifyError`. Or [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518002/1122039).

Also, there is no `IntField` in Lucene 3.6.0, i.e. the class is from Apache Solr ([class API](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_1/org/apache/solr/schema/IntField.html)) but there is one in Lucene 4.1.0. You are probably using the 3.6 version of `IntField` which is not the same as Lucene's - please check your `import` statements and your classpath.

## UPDATE

Joy, the easiest solution for you is to remove the old Lucene JAR files from `/home/abhishek/mtp/stage-2/software/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/lib` and put the new ones, and *Refresh* the project in Eclipse.

My advice for you is to switch to Apache Maven for dependency management (there is a Maven plug-in for Eclipse). In Eclipse you create a "New Maven Project" and add the dependencies to `pom.xml` file - an [example for Lucene](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/4.3.0). This way you don't have to copy any JAR files into your project or Tomcat.

Good luck.

Comment: I have imported Lucene 4.2.0 but as I am writing it as a part of Dynamic Web Project Lucene 3.6.0.jar is inlcuded in Apache Tomcat 7.0.

Comment: Check your `import` statements to see which `IntField` you are importing, the Solr (Lucene 3.6) one or Lucene 4.0. Using two different versions of a JAR is **not a good idea** as you will get strange classpath issues.

Comment: Yes Sir I have imported Lucene 4.2.0. But as I am writing it as a part of Dynamic Web Project so in Tomcat7.0 libraries a Lucene 3.6.0 is included. Is it the cause of the error?

Comment: You import statement should read `import org.apache.lucene.document.IntField;`. That should make the error go away. But two different Lucene versions are certainly the cause. You should try replacing embedded 3.6 version with the 4.1.

Comment: Yes Sir I have imported the statement. But actually I am new to developing web projects that is why I do not have much idea to do that. Could you please help me to replace the old jar file included in Tomcat library?

Comment: You should check the `${tomcat_folder}/lib/`, and remove the `*lucene-3.6*.jar` file (the file names are not exact). You could put the new `lucene-4.3.0.jar` there, but you shouldn't do that - leave the Lucene 4.3 JAR in the WebApp's `lib` folder.

Comment: You mean, if I put the Lucene new jar file in WebApps/lib folder the problem may be fixed, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31379/discussion-between-cebence-and-joy)