# getting verify error while reading .xlsx file

Tags: android, excel, exception, apache-poi, verifyerror

I am working on android application which uses Apache POI for reading and writing excel format files, while reading .xlsx file I am getting the following exception. I am trying to figure it out, but can't find any solution to the problem, if anyone knows the solution please help me. Here is the logcat error:

```
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at com.example.exc2phconverter.Homepage.onActivityResult(Homepage.java:345)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3178)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3225)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1275)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
07-08 18:22:07.350: E/AndroidRuntime(4549): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/2518002/1077035. Perhaps this can help you

Comment: I have checked this question already but not helpful

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you get the solution for this ?