# Is batik included in Netbeans 7.3.1 or higher

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

Does anybody know if Batik is included in 7.3.1 or higher ? If not, is there a Netbeans wrapper module for Batik that I can use ?

Comment: Looks like the SO nazis were here.

Comment: What's wrong with downloading the jar and include it in your project?

Comment: I already tried, I am seeing weird error and I cannot tell if that is because there is a version conflict between the one in my plugin and the one shipped by Netbeans.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393173/batik-incompatible-object-argument-for-function-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't. If you are trying to include batik in your maven based Netbeans module, please refer to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551025/netbeans-doesnt-recognize-xercesimpl/18582029#18582029).