# Incompatible argument to function

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, weblogic

My ear application runs well on Tomcat 6 on local window PC, but it cannot run on Weblogic server 10.3.6 on the same PC.

```
Caused By: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet, method: processRequest signature: (Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V) Incompatible argument to function

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
        at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.getFields.....
```

Below is part of my `pom.xml` which might be related to the problem.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
<artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder, remove all Tomcat-specific libraries like `el-ri.jar, el-api.jar`. It will make your webapp incompatible with containers of a different make/version resulting in this kind of errors.

For more info clear explanation see here

**Possible cause 1:**

`java.lang.VerifyError` can be the result when you have compiled against a different library than you are using at runtime.

Refer here [Causes of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)

**Possible cause 2:**

[How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

Specially read this paragraph

`You should above all never manually copy/download/move/include the individual servletcontainer-specific libraries like servlet-api.jar, jsp-api.jar, el-api.jar, j2ee.jar, javaee.jar, etc. It would only lead to future portability, compatibility, classpath and maintainability troubles, because your webapp would not work when it's deployed to a servletcontainer of a different make/version than where those libraries are originally obtained from.`

Comment: Great and please go through that given link thoroughly :) .

Comment: What I really say is please remove all container specific jars from pom.xml . Not at all good idea :(.

Comment: Please Check your compiled jar versions and runtime jar libraries. There might be mismatch b/w them. Check here for answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: Sure i will try to help you :)

Comment: servlet-api compiled version: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: edburns
Package: 
Build-Jdk: 1.5.0_06
Extension-Name: servlet-api
Specification-Title: A component of the Glassfish Application Server
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc
Implementation-Title: 
Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc
Implementation-Version: 2.5

Comment: servlet-api runtime version: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: R27.3.1-1-85830-1.5.0_11-20070716-1248-windows-ia32 (BEA S
 ystems, Inc.)
Implementation-Vendor: BEA Systems
Implementation-Title: Javax Enterprise Servlets  Client Capable 1.0 Th
 u Aug 2 12:41:25 EDT 2007 
Implementation-Version: 2.5
Source-Repository-Change-Id: 971320
Source-Repository-URI: p4://p4jrep.bea.com:7999://depot/dev/src/reposi
 tory/modules
Depends-On: 
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: javax.servlet

Comment: (continue for runtime version)Bundle-Name: javax.servlet
Bundle-Vendor: BEA Systems
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.0_2-5
Export-Package: javax.servlet;version=2.5,javax.servlet.http;version=2
 .5,javax.servlet.resources;version=2.5