# Trouble configuration of mockito with eclipse. Gives error: java.lang.verifyError

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mockito

When i add my mockito library to class path, and use a simple mockito example for testing where i try to return a wrong value for the function add by using the mock object, i get java.lang.verifyerror. Following is the code used for testing followed by logcat.

```
    @Test
    public void testadd()
    {
        maincode obj2=mock(maincode.class);
        when(obj2.add(0, 0)).thenReturn(9);
        assertEquals(obj2.add(0, 0),9); 
    }
```

I get the following error. Please help! thx.

> java.lang.VerifyError: org/mockito/cglib/core/ReflectUtils
>       at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:167)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)
>       at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:70)
>       at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:85)
>       at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:62)
>       at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:56)
>       at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
>       at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
>       at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
>       at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
>       at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)
>       at testaddmock.testadd(testaddmock.java:24)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
>       at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
>       at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)

Comment: this error comes due to jar issues. Are you having the correct jars in your classpath see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: I looked at the linked question.  In my case, I have only one "mockito" library on my machine (mockito-all-1.9.5.jar) so I don't see how there could be a runtime mismatch.

Comment: Maybe you have any other jar around that contains mockito classes? Try printing out the classpath (http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/) and append it to the question.

Answer (score 13):

By default, Mockito uses cglib to create dynamic proxies, but for Android this will not work, because cglib generates .class files, not .dex. But starting from version 1.9.5 Mockito offers an extension point that allows replacing the proxy generation engine, so all you need is change this engine and I think [Dexmaker](https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/) is the best variant.

So to make it works you should just add [dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar](https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/downloads/list) to your project, and Mockito will use it to generate his proxies.

Comment: as @Spec mentioned, we need the dexmaker.jar too

Answer (score 8):

@Grimmys [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21138240/236743) (+1) has the correct answer for me.

When running on Android adding the missing gradle imports for `Dexmaker` is all thats required

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5' 
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.1' 
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

@Grimmy dexmaker-1.0.jar is also needs.

@user3054298 I met the same problem & solved by following this blog's guide:http://corner.squareup.com/2012/10/mockito-android.html

> A new feature in Mockito 1.9.5 is support for Android’s Dalvik runtime. It uses DexMaker to generate mock classes on the fly. To use Mockito on a device or emulator, you’ll need to add three .jar files to your test project’s libs directory: mockito-all-1.9.5.jar, dexmaker-1.0.jar, and dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on a similar error for 3 days! Adding dexmaker libraries didn't help at all! In the end I changed the version of power mock to the latest 1.5.6 and it worked fine after that! Hope this helps someone as well.