# Apache Lucene and Hibernates search getting error

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.hibernate.search.util.impl.DelegateNamedAnalyzer overrides final method tokenStream.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Reader;)Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reasons of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means you're using a Lucene version which is different than the one compatible with your Hibernate Search version.
The compatible versions are documented on the readme or you could look at the Maven dependencies.