# Internal Server Error in Play framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I want to render a simple page in Play framework
the page is at  localhost:9000/upload

but when I try to load this page I am getting this weird stack trace. The error is not compilation nor run time. here is some lines of stack trace. 
    --- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

```
  [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000

  (Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

  [info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://192.168.2.250:3306/DP
  AU
  [info] play - Application started (Dev)
  [error] application -

  ! Internal server error, for (GET) [/indicatorupload] ->

  java.lang.VerifyError: Stack map does not match the one at exception handler 563

  Exception Details:
  Location:
  controllers/IndicatorUploadController.updateIndicatorTable(Lcontrollers/Indi
  catorUploadController$ExcelInd;I)V @563: astore_3
  Reason:
  Type 'controllers/IndicatorUploadController$ExcelInd' (current frame, locals
  [5]) is not assignable to 'models/Indicators' (stack map, locals[5])
  Current Frame:
  bci: @463
  flags: { }
  locals: { 'controllers/IndicatorUploadController$ExcelInd', integer, 'models
  /Indicators', top, top, 'controllers/IndicatorUploadController$ExcelInd', 'java/
  lang/String' }
  stack: { 'java/lang/NumberFormatException' }
  Stackmap Frame:
  bci: @563
  flags: { }
  locals: { 'controllers/IndicatorUploadController$ExcelInd', integer, 'models
  /Indicators', top, top, 'models/Indicators', 'java/lang/Object' }
   stack: { 'java/lang/NumberFormatException' }
  Bytecode:
  0000000: bb00 8e59 b700 8f4d b800 9057 2c1b 85b8
  0000010: 0091 3a06 3a05 1905 1906 b602 d92c 2a3a
  0000020: 0501 3a06 1905 b602 b23a 0619 063a 063a
  0000030: 0519 0519 06b6 02dc 2c2a 3a05 013a 0619
  0000040: 05b6 02b8 3a06 1906 3a06 3a05 1905 1906
  0000050: b602 df2c 2a3a 0501 3a06 1905 b602 be3a
  0000060: 0619 063a 063a 0519 0519 06b6 02e2 2c2a
  0000070: 3a05 013a 0619 05b6 02c7 3a06 1906 3a06
  0000080: 3a05 1905 1906 b602 e52c 2a3a 0501 3a06
  0000090: 1905 b602 e83a 0619 063a 063a 0519 0519
  00000a0: 06b6 02eb 2c2a 3a05 013a 0619 05b6 02ee
  00000b0: 3a06 1906 3a06 3a05 1905 1906 b602 f12c
  00000c0: 2a3a 0501 3a06 1905 b602 c13a 0619 063a
  00000d0: 063a 0519 0519 06b6 02f4 2c2a 3a05 013a
  00000e0: 0619 05b6 02c4 3a06 1906 3a06 3a05 1905
  00000f0: 1906 b602 f72c 2a3a 0501 3a06 1905 b602
```

I have tried setting  _JAVA_OPTION = -XX:-UseSplitVerifier in my project directory and then tried running. The cmd line should show **"Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:-UseSplitVerifier"** but I am not getting that as well. (I am confused is it JAVA_OPTION OR _JAVA_OPTION). I have even set the same JAVA_OPTION in environment variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadoc for [VerifyError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html):

> Thrown when the "verifier" detects that a class file, though well formed, contains some sort of internal inconsistency or security problem.

This error can be caused by compiling against one version of a class or library and then running against a different version of the class/library. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518002/926710) gives quite a good explanation.

```
Exception Details:

Location: controllers/IndicatorUploadController.updateIndicatorTable(Lcontrollers/IndicatorUploadController$ExcelInd;I)V @563: astore_3
Reason:
Type 'controllers/IndicatorUploadController$ExcelInd' (current frame, locals
[5]) is not assignable to 'models/Indicators' (stack map, locals[5])
```

It looks like your controller has an inner class called `ExcelInd`, which is a subclass of your `Indicators` model class. It also looks like there is a line in your `updateIndicatorTable` method that attempts to assign a value of actual type `ExcelInd` to a reference of type `Indicators`. This sounds valid, but in the code that is actually running there doesn't seem to be an inheritance relationship between the two classes.

If you've recently introduced this inheritance relationship, I would try running the `clean` task in your Play console and seeing whether a clean sorts out your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The error was caused by a bug on javaassist. With a new release 3.18.2 is solved. Add it to `project/plugins.sbt` as follows

```
libraryDependencies += "org.javassist" % "javassist" % "3.18.2-GA"
```

More about that issue [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1966#issuecomment-44357359)