# java.lang.VerifyError: main() threw exception :Incompatible argument to function

Tags: java, oozie

I am getting the above mentioned error while executing my project.
When i execute it in a normal way, it runs fine without throwing any error.
But when i try to run the same program by invoking it as a java action through oozie, it throws the following exception

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [com.ea.storage.StorageVolumeClient], main() threw exception, (class: com/ea/storage/S3Metrics, method: getS3MetricValues signature: (IJ)Ljava/util/List;) Incompatible argument to function
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/ea/storage/S3Metrics, method: getS3MetricValues signature: (IJ)Ljava/util/List;) Incompatible argument to function
    at com.ea.storage.StorageVolumeClient.storageVolume(StorageVolumeClient.java:97)
    at com.ea.storage.StorageVolumeClient.collectData(StorageVolumeClient.java:65)
    at com.ea.storage.StorageVolumeClient.main(StorageVolumeClient.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Signatur of getS3MetricValues:

```
public static List<> getS3MetricValues(int,long)
```

Place where i call the function:

```
 s3Metrics = S3Metrics.getS3MetricValues(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("pool.size")),timeout);
```

Note: I build the project on one machine and deploy it one another one.

Kindly let me know what i am missing.

Comment: can you show your code on those lines

Comment: @SaraSeppola have added the line which calls the function

Comment: okay, unfortunately i cannot help you here :/

Comment: What's the type of timeout ?

Comment: any answers on this question? Still stuck with the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reasons of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue.
This was being caused because of two jets3t libraries being loaded.
Oozie was loading jets3t version 0.6 from hadoop libs and i was loading jets3t 0.9.
Removing one of the jars solved the issue.