# java.lang.VerifyError in jsp taglib

Tags: java, jsp

I have looked at the other problems with `java.lang.VerifyError` - but can't really relate the solutions directly to my problem - so here goes.

I am migrating a java application to a new container. In the process I stumbled upon an error in regards to some of the custom jsp tag libraries.
The tag libraries are located in a jar file (which i don't have the source code for). When i start the application i get this error:

```
14:05:05,392 ERROR [[FacesServlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: dk/aaa/bbb/jsf/taglibs/ButtonTag, method: setId signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V) Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
```

As far as i can see the tld file is only exists one time on the classpath so i'm a bit lost. I hope someone can give me a hint.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: Also have a look at [JDK Bug - JDK-8004967](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8004967)