# Intellij compiler throwing "java.lang.VerifyError" Inconsistent stackmap

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Clean install of version 14 CE on OS X 10.9.5.

Originally I thought it could be because the compiler is version 1.8 and the jdk is version 1.6. I've manually configured the JVM version in Intellij properties now so that it is 1.8 (e.g. so that About intellij shows v1.8). However the problem persists. Javac on the command line works ok, just Intellij that has the problem.

Here is the error:

> Error:Internal error: (java.lang.VerifyError) Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 295
>   Exception Details:
>     Location:
>       com/intellij/openapi/util/JDOMUtil.internElement(Lorg/jdom/Element;Lcom/intellij/util/containers/StringInterner;)V @295: goto
>     Reason:
>       Type 'org/jdom/Element' (current frame, locals[4]) is not assignable to 'org/jdom/Content' (stack map, locals[4])
>     Current Frame:
>       bci: @202
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'org/jdom/Element', 'com/intellij/util/containers/StringInterner', 'java/util/Iterator', 'org/jdom/Content', 'org/jdom/Element' }
>       stack: { }
>     Stackmap Frame:
>       bci: @295
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'org/jdom/Element', 'com/intellij/util/containers/StringInterner', 'java/util/Iterator', 'org/jdom/Content', 'org/jdom/Content' }
>       stack: { }
>     Bytecode:
>       0x0000000: 2ac7 0028 bb00 4a59 124c 124d bd00 0459
>       0x0000010: 1233 128e 5359 1235 1234 5359 1232 1301
>       0x0000020: 1853 b800 3cb7 0050 bf2b c700 29bb 004a
>       0x0000030: 5912 4c12 4dbd 0004 5912 3313 011a 5359
>       0x0000040: 1235 1234 5359 1232 1301 1853 b800 3cb7
>       0x0000050: 0050 bf2a 2b2a b600 5fb8 011e b601 2257
>       0x0000060: 2ab6 0068 b900 9601 004d 2cb9 009c 0100
>       0x0000070: 9900 2a2c b900 a001 00c0 00a2 4e2d 2b2d
>       0x0000080: b600 bcb8 011e b601 2557 2d2b 2db6 00bf
>       0x0000090: b801 1eb6 0128 57a7 ffd3 2ab6 00a7 b900
>       0x00000a0: 9601 004d 2cb9 009c 0100 9900 802c b900
>       0x00000b0: a001 00c0 00a9 4e2d c100 4199 0012 2dc0
>       0x00000c0: 0041 3a04 1904 2bb8 012a a700 5d2d c100
>       0x00000d0: ab99 001b 2dc0 00ab 3a04 1904 2b19 04b6
>       0x00000e0: 00ae b801 1eb6 012e 57a7 003e 2dc1 0130
>       0x00000f0: 9900 1b2d c001 303a 0419 042b 1904 b601
>       0x0000100: 31b8 011e b601 3457 a700 1fbb 004a 59bb
>       0x0000110: 00f7 59b7 00f8 1301 12b6 00fd 2db6 0115
>       0x0000120: b601 00b7 0050 bfa7 ff7d b1
>     Stackmap Table:
>       same_frame(@41)
>       same_frame(@83)
>       append_frame(@106,Object[#152])
>       same_frame(@154)
>       same_frame(@164)
>       append_frame(@205,Object[#169])
>       same_frame(@236)
>       same_frame(@267)
>       append_frame(@295,Object[#169])
>       chop_frame(@298,2)
>   java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 295
>   Exception Details:
>     Location:
>       com/intellij/openapi/util/JDOMUtil.internElement(Lorg/jdom/Element;Lcom/intellij/util/containers/StringInterner;)V @295: goto
>     Reason:
>       Type 'org/jdom/Element' (current frame, locals[4]) is not assignable to 'org/jdom/Content' (stack map, locals[4])
>     Current Frame:
>       bci: @202
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'org/jdom/Element', 'com/intellij/util/containers/StringInterner', 'java/util/Iterator', 'org/jdom/Content', 'org/jdom/Element' }
>       stack: { }
>     Stackmap Frame:
>       bci: @295
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'org/jdom/Element', 'com/intellij/util/containers/StringInterner', 'java/util/Iterator', 'org/jdom/Content', 'org/jdom/Content' }
>       stack: { }
>     Bytecode:
>       0x0000000: 2ac7 0028 bb00 4a59 124c 124d bd00 0459
>       0x0000010: 1233 128e 5359 1235 1234 5359 1232 1301
>       0x0000020: 1853 b800 3cb7 0050 bf2b c700 29bb 004a
>       0x0000030: 5912 4c12 4dbd 0004 5912 3313 011a 5359
>       0x0000040: 1235 1234 5359 1232 1301 1853 b800 3cb7
>       0x0000050: 0050 bf2a 2b2a b600 5fb8 011e b601 2257
>       0x0000060: 2ab6 0068 b900 9601 004d 2cb9 009c 0100
>       0x0000070: 9900 2a2c b900 a001 00c0 00a2 4e2d 2b2d
>       0x0000080: b600 bcb8 011e b601 2557 2d2b 2db6 00bf
>       0x0000090: b801 1eb6 0128 57a7 ffd3 2ab6 00a7 b900
>       0x00000a0: 9601 004d 2cb9 009c 0100 9900 802c b900
>       0x00000b0: a001 00c0 00a9 4e2d c100 4199 0012 2dc0
>       0x00000c0: 0041 3a04 1904 2bb8 012a a700 5d2d c100
>       0x00000d0: ab99 001b 2dc0 00ab 3a04 1904 2b19 04b6
>       0x00000e0: 00ae b801 1eb6 012e 57a7 003e 2dc1 0130
>       0x00000f0: 9900 1b2d c001 303a 0419 042b 1904 b601
>       0x0000100: 31b8 011e b601 3457 a700 1fbb 004a 59bb
>       0x0000110: 00f7 59b7 00f8 1301 12b6 00fd 2db6 0115
>       0x0000120: b601 00b7 0050 bfa7 ff7d b1
>     Stackmap Table:
>       same_frame(@41)
>       same_frame(@83)
>       append_frame(@106,Object[#152])
>       same_frame(@154)
>       same_frame(@164)
>       append_frame(@205,Object[#169])
>       same_frame(@236)
>       same_frame(@267)
>       append_frame(@295,Object[#169])
>       chop_frame(@298,2)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.tryLoadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:87)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:72)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:43)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadComponents(JpsLoaderBase.java:55)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsGlobalLoader.loadGlobalComponents(JpsGlobalLoader.java:83)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsGlobalLoader.loadGlobalSettings(JpsGlobalLoader.java:57)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:38)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:45)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:78)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:260)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:123)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:237)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: Generally this can only happen when the .class file has been edited, though I suppose there's a remote chance that mismatched jar files or the like could be the cause.

Comment: Note that "Inconsistent stackmap frames" is a very specific error code.  It's sort of like saying that the `{` and `}` in a source file didn't match up (though that's a *very* weak analogy).  Basically, the .class file is corrupted.

Comment: Thanks JaredT - I had thought that the most likely cause is compiling on one version of the JDK and running on a different version. However, this happens even if I just "compile". IE it appears to be a compile time error rather than a runtime error.

Comment: Hot Licks - I've created three new 'HelloWorld' style java projects. Each of them has this problem. And it happens in the compile step.

Comment: Please try reinstalling IntelliJ IDEA. It's one of its classes that seems to be corrupted, not one of yours.

Comment: Hi Yole - thanks, I've done that also. Did it again just to be sure just now, same problem (VerifyError, inconsistent stackmap)

Comment: Did you figure out what was going on? I'm running into something similar in Eclipse.

Comment: no I didn't figure it out - but the same process worked on a completely new computer, so was probably some previously installed software or environment change