# Jmeter GUI testplan jmx VS Jmeter Command line testplan jmx

Tags: jmeter

- What are the differences between GUI and Non_GUI JMX files ?
- Why I am  getting these errors ?
- Can I just take a JMX file created by Jmeter
  GUI and use it on command line Jmeter ?

I tried jmeter on my windows box, works !! Now I want to run this on some remote server ( LINUX ) which does not have GUI, I tried using command line jmeter

Command : `./jmeter.sh -n -t loop.jmx -l log.jtl`

following is taken from `jmeter.log`

```
2015/03/04 14:21:53 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2015/03/04 14:21:53 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2015/03/04 14:21:53 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2015/03/04 14:21:53 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.VerifyError: org.apache.xpath.functions.SecuritySupport
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:540)
        at java.t java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue after looking at this question

- [Causes of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100107/4556894)

I also realized that, I can create JMX on GUI jmeter and use it over Commandline jmeter

Answer (score 0):

.jmx files for GUI and non-GUI aren't different, JMeter .jmx files are basically XML files. Moreover, non-GUI way is the [recommended](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) option of running a JMeter test.

So use the following checklist:

1. Use the latest JMeter version (2.12 as for now)
2. Use the latest Java version. JMeter 2.12 is compatible with Java 8. It is recommended to use Java SDK from Oracle and if your operating system allows choose 64-bit version.
3. Make sure that JVM options are identical

You can check your JVM version and vendor by executing `java --version` command.