# Library working only on >= android 5.0

Tags: java, android, jar, dependencies

I know that asking for help in this case should not be completely right but I do not know what else to do.

I'm using [this TVDB library](https://github.com/Omertron/api-thetvdb) and when running on **android >= 5.0** everything works fine. If I run it in **android < 5.0** it'll crash when calling `searchSeries` (when creating a TheTVDBApi it does not crash) and the exception says :

`Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError:  com/omertron/thetvdbapi/tools/TvdbParser
            at com.omertron.thetvdbapi.TheTVDBApi.searchSeries(TheTVDBApi.java:362)`

Do you have any suggestions? The dependencies should be right because it shouldn't work on >=5.0 if it is a dependencies problem.
If anyone has ever tried this library and it worked well below android 5.0, let me know!

These are my dependencies:

> commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10
>   commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4
>   commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2
>   commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6
>  junit:junit:jar:4.12
>   org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.4
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4
>   org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3
>   org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12
>   org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.12
>  org.yamj:api-common:jar:1.4

In the logcat it is also reported this :

> VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1918 (Ljavax/xml/ws/WebServiceException;)
>   VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0xc
>   VFY:  rejected Lcom/omertron/thetvdbapi/tools/TvdbParser;.getActors (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
>   VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x000c
>   VFY:  rejected Lcom/omertron/thetvdbapi/tools/TvdbParser;.getActors (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
>   Verifier rejected class Lcom/omertron/thetvdbapi/tools/TvdbParser;

This is what I get when calling `tvDB.searchSeries(params[0],"en");` below android 5.0 :

> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve exception class 2025 (Ljavax/xml/ws/WebServiceException;)
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0xc
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejected Lcom/omertron/thetvdbapi/tools/TvdbParser;.getActors (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x000c
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:  rejected Lcom/omertron/thetvdbapi/tools/TvdbParser;.getActors (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
>   W/dalvikvm﹕ Verifier rejected class Lcom/omertron/thetvdbapi/tools/TvdbParser;
>   W/System.err﹕ java.lang.VerifyError: com/omertron/thetvdbapi/tools/TvdbParser
>   W/System.err﹕ at com.omertron.thetvdbapi.TheTVDBApi.searchSeries(TheTVDBApi.java:362)
>   W/System.err﹕ at test.tvdb.dev.com.tvdb_test.SearchFragment$DownloadSeriesData.doInBackground(SearchFragment.java:94)
>   W/System.err﹕ at test.tvdb.dev.com.tvdb_test.SearchFragment$DownloadSeriesData.doInBackground(SearchFragment.java:77)
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

As you can see the line of code apparently causing the crash is located in TheTVDBApi library class at the 362nd row which is `return TvdbParser.getSeriesList(urlBuilder.toString(), getBannerMirror(this.apiKey));`
I don't get why is there a difference in this when running below android 5.0

Comment: Maybe it is not related to TvDB library. Check this out :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: @resw67 I really don't get why this is happening only below android 5.0 ...