# HttpClient VerifyError android

Tags: android, apache, httpclient

I am using **HttpClient 4.4.1*. When I create a `CloseableHttpClient` object, its thrown verifyError. How can I fix it?

Here is the line which thrown error:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

Error message:

```
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/DefaultHostnameVerifier
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):      at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:901)
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):      at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):      at com.srl.mbill.MeterLogin$LoginTask.doInBackground(MeterLogin.java:141)
05-06 18:22:10.911: E/AndroidRuntime(9641):      at com.srl.mbill.MeterLogin$LoginTask.doInBackground(MeterLogin.java:1)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reasons of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)

Comment: import or add updated library version......