# Android Eclipse not Responding Adding Jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I have some jar files to be added in my project.

Add those jar files as External Jar files in `Java Build Path` for my project but it has `java.lang.VerifyError` when I run the project:

```
Could not find class 'com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig', referenced from method
```

Add those jar files to my libs folder and add them in `Java Build Path`, until my PC CPU consumption around 90%.

I believe that add them either as External Jar or put them as internal Jar won't give me issue.

What's wrong with it?

**Note:** My total jars size is around 9MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally get this solved!

Got solution from [here](https://docs.oseems.com/general/application/eclipse/fix-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Need to increase:

```
-Xms512m 
-Xmx1024m
```

and

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

In my case, I need to increase all of them to `2048m`!

Answer (score 0):

The reason of java.lang.VerifyError, [Causes of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)

you should be sure the same of libraries when compiled and runtime.