# Struts unit test behavior

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, struts2

Every thing seems to be perfect until i launch all project unit tests.
After upgrade my project to struts ***2.3.15.1*** from ***2.2.1.1*** I got these errors :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
```

The problem was in fact struts 2.3.15.1 use another version of asm framework which is different from the previous one . here the result of mvn tree

```
[INFO] |  +- com.holly.project:ejbMex:ejb-client:client:8.13.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.holly.project:commons-care:jar:8.13.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.5.ga:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile

+- org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.3.15.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.struts.xwork:xwork-core:jar:2.3.15.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm-commons:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- asm:asm-tree:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- ognl:ognl:jar:3.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.11.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
```

as you can see struts use asm 3.3 which is not the one defined in hibernate transitive dependency . i solution i excluded this dependency from my struts declaration

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.15.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

The problem was solved but i'm getting now new errors which i can't figure out about what .?

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Instruction type does not match stack map in method holly.commons.ihm.utils.ServiceLocator.getMePage()Lcom.holly.project/service/IMEPage; at offset 959
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.<init>(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:55)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:59)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.createMock(EasyMock.java:103)
    at holly.commons.ihm.remote.TemplMePageTest.<init>(TemplMePageTest.java:63)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/100107/1700321.

Comment: As you mentioned this problem take place when a class has a dependency on some other class and that class has incompatibly changed after the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

@AleksandrM as Always, Thank You for your cooperation :)
In fact the problem was resolved after the exclusion also of the ***ognl*** artifact from struts core transitive dependency. it seems the version which is used to compile all the Unit Test was different from the one used to run theses ones.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.15.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ognl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>            
            </exclusions>       
        </dependency>
```