# Android testfairy java.lang.VerifyError?

Tags: java, android, mixpanel, testfairy

After I upload my apk to testfairy and install it I get a `java.lang.VerifyError` crash

The class extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

This is the function that is crashing. It crashes on the function execution, not the click but when I remove the `onClick`. Inner stuff all works.

`fitroom_lly` is `LinearLayout`

`mixpanel` defined :

```
MixpanelAPI mixpanel = MixpanelAPI.getInstance(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.Mix_Panel_Token));
```

Function:

```
private void AddOnFittingRoomClickListener() {
    fitroom_lly.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mixpanel.track("Fitting room");
        }
    });
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: co/slider/fashion/Slider/SliderFragment$6
at co.slider.fashion.Slider.SliderFragment.AddOnFittingRoomClickListener(SliderFragment.java:334)
at co.slider.fashion.Slider.SliderFragment.onCreateView(SliderFragment.java:135)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/2518002/3014866

Comment: yes but I did not help

Answer (score 1):

I work for TestFairy. I need a bit information, is your app multidex'd or a single dex? That's the only VerifyError we ever encountered, and we have an answer for that. Though I would need you to email support at testfairy.com, and one of the technical developer will explain to you the workaround. We're making this solution available to everybody, but in the meanwhile, only support is explaining this.

Comment: I dont think that my app is multidex'd, i dont believe I have over 65k functions...

Comment: I tired contacting TestFairy but there is no response