# I am getting VerifyError for RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, verifyerror

I am creating a navigation drawer with Recycler View. Earlier it was working, now suddenly I'm getting Verify Error.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.tanmay.androidsupport, PID: 18435
>                                                                              java.lang.VerifyError:
>   com/tanmay/androidsupport/view/adapter/DrawerAdapter
>                                                                                  at
>   com.tanmay.androidsupport.view.activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:75)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
>                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This is my Drawer Adapter --

```
public class DrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
Context context;
String[] navTitles;

public DrawerAdapter(Context context, String Titles[]) {
    navTitles = Titles;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vhItem = new ViewHolder(v, viewType);
        return vhItem;
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vhHeader = new ViewHolder(v, viewType);
        return vhHeader;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder.Holderid == 1) {
        holder.drawerItem.setText(navTitles[position - 1]);
    } else {

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return navTitles.length + 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position))
        return TYPE_HEADER;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    int Holderid;
    TextView drawerItem;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, int ViewType) {
        super(itemView);
        if (ViewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            drawerItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_option);
            Holderid = 1;
        } else {
            Holderid = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Line 75  HomeActivity.java... What is it? That's where your error is

Comment: @cricket_007 line 75 `HomeActivity.java -- mAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(this, ConstantClass.DRAWER, ConstantClass.DRAWER_ICONS);`

This is where I'm calling the Drawer Adapter class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you compiled against a different library than you're using at runtime.

[Have a look at this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518002/2429753)

Comment: @Exact please can you help a little more. I still can't figure it out.

Comment: @Exact The app is running perfectly on Moto G3 with Marshsmallow, but I'm getting this error on Karbonn S320 with Kitkat