# Play framework 2.5.4: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

Tags: java, playframework, verifyerror

I've migrated my project to Play 2.5.4. However, when I try to start it, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)

     java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

     java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)

     java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)

     java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)

     java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)

     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)

     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

     java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

     com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module.setupModule(Jdk8Module.java:26)

     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:524)

     play.libs.Json.newDefaultMapper(Json.java:28)

     play.libs.Json.<clinit>(Json.java:23)

     play.core.ObjectMapperProvider.get$lzycompute(ObjectMapperModule.scala:31)

     play.core.ObjectMapperProvider.get(ObjectMapperModule.scala:30)

     play.core.ObjectMapperProvider.get(ObjectMapperModule.scala:29)

     com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)

     com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)

     com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)

     com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)

     com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)

     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)

     com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)

     com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)

     com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)

     com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)

     com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)

     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)

     com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)

     com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)

     com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)

     com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)

     com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)

     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)

     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)

     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)

     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:158)

     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)

     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)

     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:155)

     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)

     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)

     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:126)

     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)

     scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)

     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:124)

     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:116)

     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)

     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)

     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)

     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)

     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)

     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)

     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

I heard that this could be a classpath issue, but I believe I don't have references to the different versions of the same lib. Here is my classpath:

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="app"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="conf"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="target\scala-2.11\src_managed\main"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="target\scala-2.11\twirl\main"/>
  <classpathentry excluding="resources\" kind="src" path="test"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\bcprov-jdk15-146.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\braintree-java-2.61.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\dom4j-1.5.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\EJML.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\gdata-client-1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\gdata-contacts-3.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\gdata-core-1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\JavaPNS_2.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\jaxen.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\jboss-client.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\jbossall-client.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\libphonenumber-7.0.9-javadoc.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\libphonenumber-7.0.9.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\log4j-1.2.13.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\maxminddb-0.3.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\metadata-extractor-2.8.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\opencsv-2.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\picketbox-4.0.21.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\quartz-2.2.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path=".\lib\xmpcore-5.1.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.scala-ide.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-enhancer\jars\play-enhancer-1.1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\twirl-api_2.11\jars\twirl-api_2.11-1.1.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\jars\commons-lang3-3.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.scala-lang.modules\scala-xml_2.11\bundles\scala-xml_2.11-1.0.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-ebean_2.11\jars\play-ebean_2.11-3.0.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-java-jdbc_2.11\jars\play-java-jdbc_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-jdbc_2.11\jars\play-jdbc_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-jdbc-api_2.11\jars\play-jdbc-api_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play_2.11\jars\play_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\build-link\jars\build-link-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-exceptions\jars\play-exceptions-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-iteratees_2.11\jars\play-iteratees_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.scala-stm\scala-stm_2.11\jars\scala-stm_2.11-0.7.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe\config\bundles\config-1.3.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\jars\logback-classic-1.1.7.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\jars\logback-core-1.1.7.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-json_2.11\jars\play-json_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-functional_2.11\jars\play-functional_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-datacommons_2.11\jars\play-datacommons_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\joda-time\joda-time\jars\joda-time-2.9.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.joda\joda-convert\jars\joda-convert-1.8.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\bundles\jackson-core-2.7.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\bundles\jackson-annotations-2.7.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\bundles\jackson-databind-2.7.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\bundles\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.7.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\bundles\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.7.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-netty-utils\jars\play-netty-utils-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\jars\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.19.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\jars\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.19.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-streams_2.11\jars\play-streams_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.reactivestreams\reactive-streams\jars\reactive-streams-1.0.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.akka\akka-stream_2.11\jars\akka-stream_2.11-2.4.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.akka\akka-actor_2.11\jars\akka-actor_2.11-2.4.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.scala-lang.modules\scala-java8-compat_2.11\bundles\scala-java8-compat_2.11-0.7.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe\ssl-config-akka_2.11\bundles\ssl-config-akka_2.11-0.2.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe\ssl-config-core_2.11\bundles\ssl-config-core_2.11-0.2.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.scala-lang.modules\scala-parser-combinators_2.11\bundles\scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.akka\akka-slf4j_2.11\jars\akka-slf4j_2.11-2.4.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\commons-codec\commons-codec\jars\commons-codec-1.10.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\xerces\xercesImpl\jars\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\xml-apis\xml-apis\jars\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\javax.transaction\jta\jars\jta-1.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.google.inject\guice\jars\guice-4.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\javax.inject\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\aopalliance\aopalliance\jars\aopalliance-1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.google.inject.extensions\guice-assistedinject\jars\guice-assistedinject-4.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.jolbox\bonecp\bundles\bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.zaxxer\HikariCP\bundles\HikariCP-2.4.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.googlecode.usc\jdbcdslog\jars\jdbcdslog-1.0.6.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.h2database\h2\jars\h2-1.4.191.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\tyrex\tyrex\jars\tyrex-1.0.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-java_2.11\jars\play-java_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.yaml\snakeyaml\bundles\snakeyaml-1.16.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.hibernate\hibernate-validator\jars\hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\javax.validation\validation-api\jars\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.jboss.logging\jboss-logging\jars\jboss-logging-3.2.1.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.fasterxml\classmate\bundles\classmate-1.1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\javax.el\javax.el-api\jars\javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.springframework\spring-context\jars\spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.springframework\spring-core\jars\spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.springframework\spring-beans\jars\spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.reflections\reflections\jars\reflections-0.9.10.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.google.guava\guava\bundles\guava-19.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\net.jodah\typetools\bundles\typetools-0.4.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\jars\jsr305-3.0.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.apache.tomcat\tomcat-servlet-api\jars\tomcat-servlet-api-8.0.33.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11\jars\play-jdbc-evolutions_2.11-2.5.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.avaje.ebeanorm\avaje-ebeanorm\jars\avaje-ebeanorm-6.18.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.jetbrains\annotations\jars\annotations-13.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\javax.persistence\persistence-api\jars\persistence-api-1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.avaje.ebeanorm\avaje-ebeanorm-agent\jars\avaje-ebeanorm-agent-4.9.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-server_2.11\jars\play-server_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-netty-server_2.11\jars\play-netty-server_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.netty\netty-reactive-streams-http\jars\netty-reactive-streams-http-1.0.6.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.netty\netty-reactive-streams\jars\netty-reactive-streams-1.0.6.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\io.netty\netty-handler\jars\netty-handler-4.0.36.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\io.netty\netty-buffer\jars\netty-buffer-4.0.36.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\io.netty\netty-common\jars\netty-common-4.0.36.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\io.netty\netty-transport\jars\netty-transport-4.0.36.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\io.netty\netty-codec\jars\netty-codec-4.0.36.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\io.netty\netty-codec-http\jars\netty-codec-http-4.0.36.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\io.netty\netty-transport-native-epoll\jars\netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.36.Final-linux-x86_64.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-logback_2.11\jars\play-logback_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-cache_2.11\jars\play-cache_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\net.sf.ehcache\ehcache-core\jars\ehcache-core-2.6.11.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-java-ws_2.11\jars\play-java-ws_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-ws_2.11\jars\play-ws_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.asynchttpclient\async-http-client\jars\async-http-client-2.0.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.asynchttpclient\netty-resolver-dns\jars\netty-resolver-dns-2.0.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.asynchttpclient\netty-resolver\jars\netty-resolver-2.0.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\jars\slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.asynchttpclient\netty-codec-dns\jars\netty-codec-dns-2.0.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.javassist\javassist\bundles\javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\oauth.signpost\signpost-core\jars\signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\oauth.signpost\signpost-commonshttp4\jars\signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.typesafe.play\play-test_2.11\jars\play-test_2.11-2.5.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\junit\junit\jars\junit-4.12.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\jars\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.novocode\junit-interface\jars\junit-interface-0.11.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.scala-sbt\test-interface\jars\test-interface-1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\net.sourceforge.htmlunit\htmlunit\jars\htmlunit-2.20.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\xalan\xalan\jars\xalan-2.7.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\xalan\serializer\jars\serializer-2.7.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient\jars\httpclient-4.5.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\jars\httpcore-4.4.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\commons-logging\commons-logging\jars\commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\jars\httpmime-4.5.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\net.sourceforge.htmlunit\htmlunit-core-js\jars\htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\net.sourceforge.nekohtml\nekohtml\jars\nekohtml-1.9.22.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\net.sourceforge.cssparser\cssparser\jars\cssparser-0.9.18.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.w3c.css\sac\jars\sac-1.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\commons-io\commons-io\jars\commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.eclipse.jetty.websocket\websocket-client\jars\websocket-client-9.2.15.v20160210.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-util\jars\jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160210.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.eclipse.jetty\jetty-io\jars\jetty-io-9.2.15.v20160210.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.eclipse.jetty.websocket\websocket-common\jars\websocket-common-9.2.15.v20160210.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.eclipse.jetty.websocket\websocket-api\jars\websocket-api-9.2.15.v20160210.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.fluentlenium\fluentlenium-core\jars\fluentlenium-core-0.10.9.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-java\jars\selenium-java-2.48.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\jars\selenium-chrome-driver-2.48.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-remote-driver\jars\selenium-remote-driver-2.48.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\cglib\cglib-nodep\jars\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\com.google.code.gson\gson\jars\gson-2.3.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-api\jars\selenium-api-2.48.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.apache.commons\commons-exec\jars\commons-exec-1.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\net.java.dev.jna\jna\jars\jna-4.1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\net.java.dev.jna\jna-platform\jars\jna-platform-4.1.0.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-edge-driver\jars\selenium-edge-driver-2.48.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-htmlunit-driver\jars\selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.48.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-support\jars\selenium-support-2.48.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\jars\selenium-firefox-driver-2.48.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-ie-driver\jars\selenium-ie-driver-2.48.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-safari-driver\jars\selenium-safari-driver-2.48.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.webbitserver\webbit\jars\webbit-0.4.14.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\io.netty\netty\bundles\netty-3.5.2.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-leg-rc\jars\selenium-leg-rc-2.48.2.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="lib" path="G:\Projects\libs\play-2.5.4\cache\org.scala-lang\scala-library\jars\scala-library-2.11.8.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Could you please help me to find out the exact root cause of the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help for now...

Comment: Can we assume from the stack trace that the problem is with google libraries?

Comment: OK, I solved the issue by deleting older libraries not only from classpath, but from "lib" folder.