# Error initializing SoapSerializationEnvelope of kSoap

Tags: android, asp.net

I am trying to link my android app to ASP.NET using kSoap library. But the problem is just when I initialize SoapSerializationEnvelope and run the app it crashes, I know this because I have commented all the other lines and tested them one by one and the only part that makes the app to crash is when SoapSerializationEnvelope is initialised. Here is my full android code that does that simple connection

```
    package com.lulliezy.realtimedata;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button generalButton;
    String namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", url = "http://192.168.x.x/RealtimeDataServer/MainWebService.asmx";
    SoapObject requests;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
    HttpTransportSE transport;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        generalButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generalButton);


        generalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    requests = new SoapObject(namespace, "FetchField");
                    envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(requests);
                    transport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
                    transport.call(namespace+"FetchField", envelope);
                    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am new to this and I just wrote a simple program and a simple web service just to get it up and running first. Here is the ASP.NET webmethod

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class MainWebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()>
    Public Function FetchField() As String
        Return "Trial worked"
    End Function

End Class
```

Any help will be highly appreciated and thanx in advance

Stack trace is

```
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.lulliezy.realtimedata, PID: 2234
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.lulliezy.realtimedata.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4496)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18603)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 10:57:20.096 2234-2234/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2234 SIG: 9
```

this couldn't fit in the comment

this is the whole logcat if it will be of any help

```
07-18 10:57:09.926 2234-2234/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
07-18 10:57:09.926 2234-2234/? I/SELinux:  
07-18 10:57:09.926 2234-2234/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1], There is no sepolicy version file.
07-18 10:57:09.926 2234-2234/? I/SELinux:  
07-18 10:57:09.926 2234-2234/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority is 3. priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-G530H_4.4.4_0033
07-18 10:57:09.926 2234-2234/? I/SELinux:  
07-18 10:57:09.926 2234-2234/? I/SELinux:  
07-18 10:57:09.926 2234-2234/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> Normal User
07-18 10:57:09.926 2234-2234/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.lulliezy.realtimedata [ userId:0 | appId:10111 ]
07-18 10:57:09.926 2234-2234/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-18 10:57:09.986 2234-2234/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: in addTimaSignatureService
07-18 10:57:09.996 2234-2234/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: Cannot add TimaSignature Service, License check Failed
07-18 10:57:09.996 2234-2234/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKesytore provider
07-18 10:57:10.156 2234-2234/? D/DisplayManagerGlobal: getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 540 x 960, real 540 x 960, largest app 960 x 922, smallest app 540 x 502, 60.0 fps, rotation0, density 240 (221.225 x 221.672) dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
07-18 10:57:10.156 2234-2234/? D/DisplayManagerGlobal: getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 540 x 960, real 540 x 960, largest app 960 x 922, smallest app 540 x 502, 60.0 fps, rotation0, density 240 (221.225 x 221.672) dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
07-18 10:57:10.156 2234-2234/? D/ActivityThread: handleBindApplication:com.lulliezy.realtimedata
07-18 10:57:10.156 2234-2234/? D/DisplayManagerGlobal: getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 540 x 960, real 540 x 960, largest app 960 x 922, smallest app 540 x 502, 60.0 fps, rotation0, density 240 (221.225 x 221.672) dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
07-18 10:57:10.156 2234-2234/? D/DisplayManagerGlobal: getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 540 x 960, real 540 x 960, largest app 960 x 922, smallest app 540 x 502, 60.0 fps, rotation0, density 240 (221.225 x 221.672) dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
07-18 10:57:10.296 2234-2234/? W/ApplicationPackageManager: getCSCPackageItemText()
07-18 10:57:10.296 2234-2234/? D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
07-18 10:57:10.306 2234-2234/? D/DisplayManagerGlobal: getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 540 x 960, real 540 x 960, largest app 960 x 922, smallest app 540 x 502, 60.0 fps, rotation0, density 240 (221.225 x 221.672) dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
07-18 10:57:10.316 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
07-18 10:57:10.316 2234-2234/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
07-18 10:57:10.316 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15448: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
07-18 10:57:10.316 2234-2234/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
07-18 10:57:10.316 2234-2234/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
07-18 10:57:10.316 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15452: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
07-18 10:57:10.316 2234-2234/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
07-18 10:57:10.336 2234-2234/? D/DisplayManagerGlobal: getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 540 x 960, real 540 x 960, largest app 960 x 922, smallest app 540 x 502, 60.0 fps, rotation0, density 240 (221.225 x 221.672) dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
07-18 10:57:10.456 2234-2234/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
07-18 10:57:10.456 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 415: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
07-18 10:57:10.456 2234-2234/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-18 10:57:10.456 2234-2234/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
07-18 10:57:10.456 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 437: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
07-18 10:57:10.456 2234-2234/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-18 10:57:10.566 2234-2234/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
07-18 10:57:10.566 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 378: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
07-18 10:57:10.566 2234-2234/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-18 10:57:10.566 2234-2234/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
07-18 10:57:10.566 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 380: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
07-18 10:57:10.566 2234-2234/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-18 10:57:10.666 2234-2234/? D/DisplayManagerGlobal: getDisplayInfo: displayId=0, info=DisplayInfo{"Built-in Screen", app 540 x 960, real 540 x 960, largest app 960 x 922, smallest app 540 x 502, 60.0 fps, rotation0, density 240 (221.225 x 221.672) dpi, layerStack 0, type BUILT_IN, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
07-18 10:57:10.826 2234-2234/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
07-18 10:57:10.826 2234-2234/? I/Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.02.07
07-18 10:57:10.826 2234-2234/? I/Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 08/06/14 Wed
07-18 10:57:10.826 2234-2234/? I/Adreno-EGL: Local Branch: rb1
07-18 10:57:10.826 2234-2234/? I/Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: 
07-18 10:57:10.826 2234-2234/? I/Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: 
07-18 10:57:10.826 2234-2234/? I/Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: 
07-18 10:57:11.086 2234-2234/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
07-18 10:57:12.286 2234-2234/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41ec9e18 time:43737788
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.kxml2.kdom.Node', referenced from method org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parseBody
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 2158 (Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;) in Lorg/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope;
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x002f
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.kxml2.kdom.Node', referenced from method org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parseHeader
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2158 (Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;) in Lorg/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope;
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0003
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.kxml2.kdom.Node', referenced from method org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.writeBody
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2158 (Lorg/kxml2/kdom/Node;) in Lorg/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope;
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000f
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: array-length on non-array
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x21 at 0x0007
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Lorg/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope;.writeHeader (Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlSerializer;)V
07-18 10:57:16.066 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: Verifier rejected class Lorg/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope;
07-18 10:57:16.096 2234-2234/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-18 10:57:16.096 2234-2234/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416a8d58)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.lulliezy.realtimedata, PID: 2234
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.lulliezy.realtimedata.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4496)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18603)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
07-18 10:57:16.136 2234-2234/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 10:57:20.096 2234-2234/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2234 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What is the stack trace from the application?

Comment: just edited it @LarsNielsen because it couldn't fit in the comment

Comment: maybe this is your problem?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/reasons-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: it seems that i need this library **ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar** but all the google links are broken so does anyone know a link that i can use to download the library

Comment: Update your version, but here: https://github.com/lishuyuan/ksoap2-android/tree/master/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.6.2

Comment: Current version is 3.6.1

Comment: thanx @LarsNielsen i got it

Comment: The library helped fix my issue