# Execption in thread main : java.lang.verifyError

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to run the framerwork hadoopizer with hadoop , I'm using hadoop 2.7.3 and jdk 8  but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTrackerInstrumentation.create(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker;Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTrackerInstrumentation; @5: invokestatic
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/lib/DefaultMetricsSystem' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/MetricsSystem'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @5
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker', 'org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker', 'org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf', 'org/apache/hadoop/metrics2/lib/DefaultMetricsSystem' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2b b200 03b8 0004 b0                 

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner.<init>(LocalJobRunner.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:457)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$1.run(Job.java:513)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
    at org.genouest.hadoopizer.Hadoopizer.main(Hadoopizer.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

is there a problem with the version of java or what , I didn't understand the error

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror) ... and hint: try using your favorite search engine the next time. You don't need other people in order to put a few keywords (like the exception name) into google ...

Comment: Having said so; that duplicate looks pretty much like yours.