# Mockito: mock-maker-inline Android GcmNetworkManager mock java.lang.VerifyError Google Play Services v11.0.2

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, google-play-services

Mocking Android's `GcmNetworkManager` with `mock-maker-inline` results in `java.lang.VerifyError` for Google Play Services version `11.0.2` but not `10.2.6`.

I have been using Mockito `2.2.22` but updated to latest (`2.8.47`) to see if it rectified the issue.  Stack traces for both cases provided below.

#### Java Version

```
$ /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_112-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b06, mixed mode)
```

#### Minimal Example

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmNetworkManager;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UnitTest {
    private @Mock GcmNetworkManager gcmNetworkManager;

    @Test
    public void doesNothing() { /* empty */ }
}
```

#### Stack Trace - Mockito v2.2.22

```
objc[32228]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10e0464c0) and /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x115c5f4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

java.lang.VerifyError
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:112)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:92)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$CachedBytecodeGenerator.getOrGenerateMockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:91)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:38)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:168)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:149)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:63)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1637)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:39)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.process(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:63)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:43)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:67)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.SilentJUnitRunner$1.withBefores(SilentJUnitRunner.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.SilentJUnitRunner.run(SilentJUnitRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


Test ignored.
Process finished with exit code 255
```

#### Stack Trace - Mockito v2.8.47

```
objc[32710]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x101b9c4c0) and /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1207be4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmNetworkManager.

If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : JetBrains s.r.o
JVM vendor version : 25.112-b06
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0_112-release-b06
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Mac OS X
OS version         : 10.12.6


You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks.
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.

Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type

    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.withBefores(DefaultInternalRunner.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:78)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:84)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:161)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:140)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:201)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:182)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:63)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1729)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:38)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:117)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:97)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:37)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:34)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)
    ... 40 more


Test ignored.
Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit:

This should be fixed in Mockito 2.9.0
Source: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/944

The workaround below should not be needed if you upgrade Mockito.

---

This could happen when instrumenting obfuscated classes that do not correctly retain type information within a method that's called.

I managed to fix it by telling the JVM not to verify the classes in unit tests in my build.gradle:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        jvmArgs '-noverify'
    }
}
```

There's some suggestion that this is a bug in Proguard and you'll be seeing it because the GcmNetworkManager has been obfuscated using Proguard.

Sources:
https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1078, https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1000

Answer (score 0):

This [error](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-verifyerror-how-to-solve-verifyerror/)  indicates that the verifier, included in the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), detected a class file that despite well formed, it contains some type of internal inconsistency or faces a security problem.

> The [`VerifyError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html) class extends the [`LinkageError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/LinkageError.html) class, which is used to indicate those error cases, where a class has a dependency on some other class and that class has incompatibly changed after the compilation. Furthermore, the [`LinkageError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/LinkageError.html) class extends the [`Error`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) class, which is used to indicate those serious problems that an application should not catch. A method may not declare such errors in its `throw` clause, because these errors are abnormal conditions that shall never occur.

In order to avoid the `VerifyError`, you must compile all your classes using the same version of Java. Also, once you make a change to a class, then make sure that you re-compile your project from scratch. Finally, if your application makes use of external libraries, verify that you use the appropriate version of every library and of course, consult the corresponding javadocs, in order to be sure that everything is correct.

You may also check this related post:

- [Causes of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)

Hope this helps!