# app crashes in android 4.4 versions and give below error . and worked great from android 5.0 versions

Tags: android

I develope app for supports android 4.4 and up 
i gave min sdk version 19 and targeted version 25 , but my app crashes in android 4.4 and working great in android 5.0

this is my logcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp, PID: 7367 java.lang.VerifyError: com / Forewarn / ForewarnApp / activities / SignInActivity
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java: 1208)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java: 1061)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2286)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java: 145)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1243)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5127)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: is this a full stack error u just posted ?

Comment: yes ..this only i got

Comment: i think you are using appcompatactivity(extending from appCompatActivity). if yes. then either changeit to activity or add library to give backward compatibility for 4.4

Comment: all activities of my application i use appCompatActivity i extened for set actionbar title purpose.can i change all activities of appCompat to activity?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror check this link

Comment: what are you using ? Activity or AppCompatActivity ?

Comment: i changed appCompat to Activity but still same error

Comment: @himel i used AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

do this , do a clean/rebuild project then test , `java.lang.VerifyError` happens if there is a compiling error in generating byte code.

Comment: try invalidate chaches/restart ,then see what happens

Comment: colse the project , start a new one ,see if the error appears in that also.

Comment: im sorry , but still same error.. i think this is not a compiling error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your library dependencies defined in gradle must be of same version.

Comment: compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.2.2.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'