# I'm getting error when running my app using android 4.4 and 8.1 (api level 19 & 27) on tablets/mobile phones

Tags: android

This ClassNotFound exception came when I run it on android 4.4 devices, I wonder how did it happen, because I have already registered all of my activities under my manifest file, but still this error is occurring again and it makes me confused.
Please can anyone suggest me what is wrong with my code:

Here is error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp.activities.Splash Activity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp-2, /system/lib]]
```

Here is manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <configuration>
        <release>
            true
        </release>
    </configuration>

    <permission
        android:name="com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:name=".activities.SoteriaApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcherr"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SignInActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.SignUpActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ForgotPasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.SerachResultsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.DetailsPageActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.PropertyDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.BankurptsDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.SampleActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ActivityCallLog" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.SettingsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.VehicleDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ResultsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.OthersActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.NoRecordsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.MoreRecordsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.CriminalDetailsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.CriminalSampleActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.OtpActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.AddressesDetailsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.PhonesHistoryDetailsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ContactsReaderActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.FingerprintTermsAndConditionsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ChangePasswordActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.TermsandConditionsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.PdfPasswordActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and btw i put my minsdkversion = 19
maxsdkversion = 27 
and error getting app crashed on android 8.1.0 (api level 27) devices also.

here is my application class code :

```
public class SoteriaApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AccountUtils.assignContext(this);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

btw i tried with instant run disabling method: now i get verify error : like this :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp, PID: 1060
                                                                        java.lang.VerifyError: com/Forewarn/ForewarnApp/activities/SignInActivity
                                                                            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try my answer.....

Comment: show your Manifest

Comment: can you please have a look up,i added my manifest already when i ask question

Comment: Do Invalidate Chache and Restart in Android Studio and Clean and Build Project

Comment: @aravindhnani check my upadte2 in answer

Comment: isaw updated2 ans but i dont know what i need to change, thats not understandable

Answer (score 1):

Sound Like a Multidex issue. In your Application Class `activities.SoteriaApplication` Add this

```
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
  }
```

**app.gradle**

```
android {
 defaultConfig {
      multiDexEnabled true
  }
 dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

Enable Multidex in Gradle too

**NB :** Use `android:name=".activities.SoteriaApplication"` only if This is Your Custom Appplication Class

Also Try Clean And Rebuild the Project and Run Application without Instant Run. Check Whether problem is resolved

Comment: can u please have a look at my updated code now once again, i added my application class, and suggest me if thats wrong

Comment: Do U having Proguard Rules

Comment: In Some Cases Due to IntantRun Feature of Android Studio Will Show This  Error

Comment: sorry idk about proguard rules. i'm newer to android.

Comment: Clean And Rebuild the Project and Run Application without Instant Run. Check Whetehr problem is resolved

Comment: sorry. it's not solved yet. i'd been tried alot of times with this logic

Comment: @aravindhnani if u didn't add any pro guard rule in the file. Don't worry about it. proguardrules are used to reduce application size by removing unused classes and Object

Comment: Try adding Heap Size for DexOptioon. Just Like What im added in Edit @aravindhnani

Answer (score 0):

**Update2**(After reading your updated question and error log)

I have seen that you have verifier log , so let me describe it hope that you can get some clue. [Here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-verifyerror-how-to-solve-verifyerror/) is this discussion in detail.

> This error indicates that the verifier, included in the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), detected a class file that despite well formed, it contains some type of internal inconsistency or faces a security problem.
>
> The VerifyError class extends the LinkageError class, which is used to
>   indicate those error cases, where a class has a dependency on some
>   other class and that class has incompatibly changed after the
>   compilation. Furthermore, the LinkageError class extends the Error
>   class, which is used to indicate those serious problems that an
>   application should not catch. A method may not declare such errors in
>   its throw clause, because these errors are abnormal conditions that
>   shall never occur.
>
> Finally, the VerifyError exists since the 1.0 version of Java.

**For me this could be your case. Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror) SO question and check your dependencies. Clean your project. or even restart your system. I do believe it is not cleaning your project rightly.**

**Update1**
I have the same problem. How I solved it is by adding following line in build.gradle file dependencies.

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

**then  in my Application class i extend it with "extends MultiDexApplication"  I made sure to add this  in onCreate method .** like

```
public class SoteriaApplication extends MultiDexApplication  {
//Please extend your application class with MultiDexApplication 
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AccountUtils.assignContext(this);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}}
```

> Please extend you application class with MultiDexApplication class.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing-:

```
Go to File on top menu->Setting->Build Execution->Instant run->If its enabled then try disabling that.
```

Comment: can u see my updated code , i get one more error, when i try with disable instant run option

Comment: verify error it says, but idk how it'll resolve. it doesn't have any clue

Comment: why you using this Forewarn.ForewarnApp??

Comment: my company name and my appliaction names

Comment: oh ok...instant run did it or not?

Comment: i disabled it, then also not solving issue

Answer (score 0):

If you have done the `MultiDex` work mentioned by @A.s.ALI and @Tomin B Azhakathu and still have the `ClassNotFoundException`. Then you should look up if the `com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp.activities.SplashActivity` is in the `main dex`(You can drag your apk just in the Android Studio and confirm it). If `com.Forewarn.ForewarnApp.activities.SplashActivity` is in the `main dex`, and still throw the exception just let me know, thx.