# Rest API gives (jaxb) java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, moxy, verifyerror

So i'm trying to write a java Rest API. While the other Rest API works, this one gives the underlying error. I'm using a tomcat server. The thing is that I have no idea what i'm doing wrong. It gives the java.lang.verifyError.

Thanks in advance!

This is the DAO function:

```
public Collection<CFUser> getUsers() {
    Query q;
    q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM CFUser u");
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

This is the REST call:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Collection<CFUser> getUsers() {
        return DAO.getInstance().getUsers();
}
```

This is the received error:

```
Type Exception Report

Message org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: 
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/generated0, 
method: setValue signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)V) Incompatible argument to 
function

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it 
from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/generated0, method: setValue signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)V) Incompatible argument to function
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:392)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Root Cause

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/generated0, method: setValue signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)V) Incompatible argument to function
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:249)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:231)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:436)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:265)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Root Cause

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/eclipse/persistence/jaxb/generated0, method: setValue signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)V) Incompatible argument to function
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getClassForName(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:124)
org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.AggregateMapping.convertClassNamesToClasses(AggregateMapping.java:374)
org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractCompositeCollectionMapping.convertClassNamesToClasses(AbstractCompositeCollectionMapping.java:289)
org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping.convertClassNamesToClasses(XMLCompositeCollectionMapping.java:304)
org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.convertClassNamesToClasses(ClassDescriptor.java:1656)
org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLDescriptor.convertClassNamesToClasses(XMLDescriptor.java:1104)
org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Project.convertClassNamesToClasses(Project.java:514)
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1105)
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1089)
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:189)
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:165)
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:152)
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:112)
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:102)
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.getJAXBContext(MOXyJsonProvider.java:303)
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.getJAXBContext(MOXyJsonProvider.java:322)
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.isWriteable(MOXyJsonProvider.java:534)
org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.internal.ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider.isWriteable(ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider.java:190)
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.isWriteable(MOXyJsonProvider.java:532)
org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.internal.ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider.isWriteable(ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider.java:190)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory$MbwModel.isWriteable(MessageBodyFactory.java:274)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory$MbwModel.isWriteable(MessageBodyFactory.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyWriter(MessageBodyFactory.java:858)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyWriter(MessageBodyFactory.java:822)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:223)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:103)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:88)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:149)
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1139)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:574)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:381)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:371)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:262)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:318)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1010)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

CFUser:

```
package Classes;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import Playfield.Player;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author gebruiker
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "CFUser")
@XmlRootElement
public class CFUser implements Serializable, IDataBaseObject {

//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="variables">    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic//(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "User_id")
    private int UserId;

    @Column(name = "User_active")
    private Boolean UserActive;

    @Column(name = "User_classname")
    private String UserClassname;

    @Basic//(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "User_firstname")
    private String UserFirstname;

    @Column(name = "User_clan")
    private Clan userClan;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "User_lastname")
    private String UserLastname;

    @Column(name = "User_level")
    private BigInteger UserLevel;

    @Column(name = "User_password", nullable = false)
    private String UserPassword;

    @Basic//(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "User_role")
    private String UserRole;

    @Column(name = "User_Username", nullable = false)
    private String Username;

    @Column(name = "User_location")
    private BigInteger UserLocation;

    @Basic
    HashMap<Long, int[]> History;// hashmap which maps lesson id to an array of int[0] id exersize, int[1] phase

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "members")
    private List<ClassGroup> classGroups;

    @OneToOne
    private ClassGroup currentGroup;

    public ClassGroup getCurrentGroup() {
        return currentGroup;
    }

    public void setCurrentGroup(ClassGroup currentGroup) {
        this.currentGroup = currentGroup;
    }

//</editor-fold>
//<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="functions">        
    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return UserId;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(int UserId) {
        this.UserId = UserId;
    }

    public Boolean getUserActive() {
        return UserActive;
    }

    public void setUserActive(Boolean UserActive) {
        this.UserActive = UserActive;
    }

    public String getUserClassname() {
        return UserClassname;
    }

    public void setUserClassname(String UserClassname) {
        this.UserClassname = UserClassname;
    }

    public String getUserFirstname() {
        return UserFirstname;
    }

    public void setUserFirstname(String UserFirstname) {
        this.UserFirstname = UserFirstname;
    }

    public Clan getUserClan() {
        return userClan;
    }

    public void setUserClan(Clan userClan) {
        this.userClan = userClan;
    }

    public String getUserLastname() {
        return UserLastname;
    }

    public void setUserLastname(String UserLastname) {
        this.UserLastname = UserLastname;
    }

    public BigInteger getUserLevel() {
        return UserLevel;
    }

    public void setUserLevel(BigInteger UserLevel) {
        this.UserLevel = UserLevel;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return UserPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String UserPassword) {
        this.UserPassword = UserPassword;
    }

    public String getUserRole() {
        return UserRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(String UserRole) {
        this.UserRole = UserRole;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String Username) {
        this.Username = Username;
    }

    public BigInteger getUserLocation() {
        return UserLocation;
    }

    public void setUserLocation(BigInteger UserLocation) {
        this.UserLocation = UserLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 71 * hash + this.UserId;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final CFUser other = (CFUser) obj;
        if (this.UserId != other.UserId) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Generated_classes.Users[ UserId=" + UserId + " ]";
    }

    public HashMap<Long, int[]> getHistory() {
        return History;
    }

    public void setHistory(HashMap<Long, int[]> History) {
        this.History = History;
    }

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Player player;

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
        if (player.getUser() != this) {
            player.setUser(this);
        }
    }

    public List<ClassGroup> getClassGroups() {
        return classGroups;
    }

    public void setClassGroups(List<ClassGroup> classGroups) {
        this.classGroups = classGroups;
    }

//</editor-fold>
}
```

Comment: Post the `CFUser` code please.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Causes of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)

Comment: @daniu I did now

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly because of library changes and also might have resulted when you have compiled against a different library and you might use another at run-time.

Comment: And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: @RobinGoussey Compile against exactly the same library you are using in the runtime.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans, where i just run it, so it compiles automatically. So how do I get the runtime library?