# java.lang.VerifyError: in tomcat in fedora env

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

Gettung bellow error while bringing up tomcat.
But the war is running in other systems without any error.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/company/project/jaxws_asm/RegisterPartner, method: setAuthInfo signature: (Lcom/company/project/AuthInfo;)V) Illegal instruction found at offset 1
```

Any help will be greatly expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Causes of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was, that I had two ASM versions on the classpath.

- ASM 3.1.0
- ASM 5.0.4

I removed 3.1.0 and it worked fine.