# Application not starting in Tomcat 9.0.12

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jackson, jersey

We have one application running in lower environments without any issues but failing to start with below exception in production. Can somebody help me?

The code builds perfectly without issues and when we try to deploy generated war file in Tomcat server it fails to start with bellow error. I tried to take the war file from production and deploy in lower environments it works perfectly.

```
25-Oct-2018 18:05:46.692 SEVERE [main] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending 
context initialized event to listener instance of class 
[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchProcessUtility': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.company.service.rest.iface.RestVehicleInformationIFace com.company.batch.utility.BatchProcessUtility.vehicleRestInformationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restVehicleInformationImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate com.company.service.rest.impl.RestVehicleInformationImpl.restTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-app-rest-services.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper, method: writeValueAsBytes signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)[B) Incompatible argument to function
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:574)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5109)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:969)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.company.service.rest.iface.RestVehicleInformationIFace com.company.batch.utility.BatchProcessUtility.vehicleRestInformationService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restVehicleInformationImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate com.company.service.rest.impl.RestVehicleInformationImpl.restTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-app-rest-services.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper, method: writeValueAsBytes signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)[B) Incompatible argument to function
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restVehicleInformationImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate com.company.service.rest.impl.RestVehicleInformationImpl.restTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-app-rest-services.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper, method: writeValueAsBytes signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)[B) Incompatible argument to function
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:838)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:780)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate com.company.service.rest.impl.RestVehicleInformationImpl.restTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-app-rest-services.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper, method: writeValueAsBytes signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)[B) Incompatible argument to function
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-app-rest-services.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper, method: writeValueAsBytes signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)[B) Incompatible argument to function
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:901)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:838)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:780)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper, method: writeValueAsBytes signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)[B) Incompatible argument to function
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:71)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:948)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper, method: writeValueAsBytes signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)[B) Incompatible argument to function
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.<init>(RestTemplate.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 82 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the Tomcat setup is different across different environments:

- use different Java version when running Tomcat on different environments
- using `-noverify` or similar flags when running Tomcat on lower environments
- added JARs into `TOMCAT_HOME\lib` that conflict with the ones shipped inside your WAR on production environment

As per [this answer on VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror):

> Normally, the compiler will flag problems where method signatures do not match. The JVM will verify the bytecode again when the class is loaded, and throws VerifyError when the bytecode is trying to do something that should not be allowed -- e.g. calling a method that returns String and then stores that return value in a field that holds a List.

Comment: Thanks for  the response. how to set -noverif or similar flags on tomcat?

Comment: @Avi There are multiple ways to do it. Do note that `-noverify` is a workaround for old libraries that failed to catch up with JDK stack verification changes, you are not supposed to use it as a workaround on production.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of jackson jar file that is in your lib folder of your webapp. If it is not there, then you are using the version of jar which comes with tomcat.
In such a case the jackson version in your tomcat is different from the tomcat on which you are deploying your project.

You can add jackson jar to your lib folder and restart tomcat. Check the below method in your jackon jar file.

```
org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper, method: writeValueAsBytes signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)[B) Incompatible argument to function
```