# Are there serious compatibility issues with Java8 and JBoss EAP 7 for deploying web services with JBOSS developer studio

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jboss7.x, wildfire-api

When I set my server to deploy my .war file I get this error log on JBoss dev studio:

I am using Java 1.8.0-161 and also JBOSS EAP 7.0.0.GA Core 2.1.2.Final-redhat-1 with JBOSS Red Hat Developer Studio version 10.4.0.GA trying to deploy a service which is really an old one too. But worked well before. But I get the following error log and the installation is aborted.

```
10:37:36,403 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-1) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@551b90d9: defining beans [supportsTransactionTemplate,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,berichtFactoryComponent,protokollService]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2f390677
10:37:37,653 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-1) Creating Service {http://webservice.webkash.bgs.datagroup.de/import/V1}KashEImportWebserviceImplService from class de.datagroup.bgs.kashe.webservice.KashEImportWebserviceImpl
10:37:37,676 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Web.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Web.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "Web.war"
      at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154) [wildfly-server-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.6.Final-redhat-1]
      at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.2.6.Final-redhat-1]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: de/datagroup/bgs/kashe/webservice/jaxws_asm/ImportData, method: setImportRequest signature: (Lde/datagroup/bgs/kashe/webservice/model/ImportRequest;)V) Illegal instruction found at offset 1
      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]
      at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]
      at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]
      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]
      at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil$4.run(ReflectionUtil.java:105)
      at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil$4.run(ReflectionUtil.java:102)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_161]
      at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredConstructor(ReflectionUtil.java:102)
      at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.getValidClass(JAXBUtils.java:582)
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(JAXBContextInitializer.java:309)
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBContextInitializer.begin(JAXBContextInitializer.java:187)
      at org.apache.cxf.service.ServiceModelVisitor.visitOperation(ServiceModelVisitor.java:97)
      at org.apache.cxf.service.ServiceModelVisitor.walk(ServiceModelVisitor.java:74)
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:315)
      at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
      at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:467)
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:696)
      at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:527)
      at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:261)
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199)
      at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
      at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:168)
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:460)
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:338)
      at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:79)
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:255)
      at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:543)
      at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.BusHolder.configure(BusHolder.java:234)
      at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:97)
      at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:59)
      at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:73)
      at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147) [wildfly-server-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
      ... 5 more

10:37:37,676 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Web.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Web.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Web.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"Web.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: de/datagroup/bgs/kashe/webservice/jaxws_asm/ImportData, method: setImportRequest signature: (Lde/datagroup/bgs/kashe/webservice/model/ImportRequest;)V) Illegal instruction found at offset 1"}}
10:37:37,801 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "Web.war" (runtime-name : "Web.war")
10:37:37,801 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Web.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Web.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "Web.war"

10:37:38,020 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
10:37:38,020 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
10:37:38,020 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: JBoss EAP 7.0.0.GA (WildFly Core 2.1.2.Final-redhat-1) started (with errors) in 38736ms - Started 259 of 449 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 251 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
10:37:38,098 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final-redhat-1
10:37:41,473 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment Web.war (runtime-name: Web.war) in 3406ms
10:37:41,556 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location C:\Users\KASHAd\devstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\standalone\data\content\76\c572c3aa6c2bac786b47d25711fe91d5708b64\content
10:37:41,556 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0009: Undeployed "Web.war" (runtime-name: "Web.war")
10:37:41,556 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Web.war".INSTALL
```

This is running on a windows server 2012 RC2. I have tried to reconfigure the standalone.xml file over and over but nothing has helped.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror), `java.lang.VerifyError` might occur when you have compiled against a different library than you're actually using at runtime. Particularly in this case, I guess you're using a different JDK for compiling and executing, possibly because the default on Developer Studio changed.

Comment: Thank you Francisco for your answer. I suspected that but was not gifted enough to be able to correct the error. Do you have any tips you could share with me? Would it suffice to upgrade my JDK?

Comment: I would most definitely install the latest openjdk 1.8 and recompile everything again.