# java.lang.VerifyError:Illegal type in constant pool

Tags: java, xml, spring-cloud, mvel, azure-spring-cloud

When sending and reading xml files through rest api post endpoint in Azure Spring Cloud App with less than 100 rows, the code works, but if one runs more than 100 rows xml file, Azure Spring Cloud throws the following error: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: ASMAccessorImpl_121123687416524427187737, method: getValue signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/mvel2/integration/VariableResolverFactory;)Ljava/lang/Object;) Illegal type in constant pool.

What is wrong? How to fix this? The same code and xml files work locally with more than 100 rows.

Comment: Can you provide more info, for example:
azure cli request with parameters or the api request, what is the xml providing, what is supposed to happen when the xml file is read

Comment: @djmonki This is now solved, it was probably caused by bytecode size of my method exceeded the 64kb limit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved, it was probably caused by bytecode size of one of my methods exceeded the 64kb limit. [Causes of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)