# java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type

Tags: java, gradle

I am facing the below issue when running my jar:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory.getFactory()Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$1' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { }
    stack: { 'org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory$1' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: bb00 0559 b700 06b0

        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:195)
        at com.philips.asp.container.cv.CvEtlApplication.main(CvEtlApplication.java:20)
        ... 8 more
```

I am using Java 11 and gradle 4.10.2.
And dependency task gives below output:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Causes of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100107/causes-of-getting-a-java-lang-verifyerror)